# Identificar una excepción específica al restablecerse la conexión a una BD remota en Java 8 y c3p0

Tags: java, base-de-datos, c3p0

Tengo un proyecto en Netbeans que se conecta a una base de datos remota usando un pool de conexiones con la librería c3p0. La conexión con la BD en producción no es confiable, así que para reproducir este escenario simplemente activo y desactivo mi conexión ethernet. Mi problema es que al restablecer la conexión ethernet e intentar adquirir una conexión a la BD desde el pool de conexiones, se me genera una SQLException, la que quiero identificar. Mi código es éste:

```
// https://hashblogeando.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/pooling-de-conexiones-a-base-de-datos-con-c3p0-y-java/
cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
cpds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://someserver:5432/sample1");
  cpds.setUser("usuario");
  cpds.setPassword("contrasena"); 
  // Numero de conexiones con las que iniciara el pool
  cpds.setInitialPoolSize(1);
  // Minimo de conexiones que tendra el pool
  cpds.setMinPoolSize(1);
  // Numero de conexiones a crear cada incremento
  cpds.setAcquireIncrement(1);
  // Maximo numero de conexiones
  cpds.setMaxPoolSize(50);
  // Maximo numero de reintentos para conectar a base de datos
  cpds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(1);
  // Que se genere una excepcion si no se puede conectar
  cpds.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(true);
// si pongo cpds.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(false); no se genera la excepción
// pero yo quiero que se genere y poderla identificar

  try(Connection con = cpds.getConnection()) // la excepción se lanza aquí
  {
      // código para insertar y actualizar valores
  }
  catch(SQLException e)
  {
      // quiero identificar la excepción que se lanza al restablecerse la conexión con la bd, no al caerse la conexión
      System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.err.println(e.getCause());
        System.err.println(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
  }
```

El mensaje de la excepción es:

> "e = (java.sql.SQLException) java.sql.SQLException: An SQLException
>   was provoked by the following failure:
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: Attempted to use a
>   closed or broken resource pool"

Esto es lo que se imprime con `System.err.println(e.getCause())`

> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: Attempted to use a
>   closed or broken resource pool

Y esto es lo que se imprime con `System.err.println(Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()))`

> [com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118),
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77),
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:74),
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:694),
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140),
>   mypackage.myClass.FunctionThatTriesToConnect(myClass.java:119)]

¿hay alguna forma de identificar específicamente esta excepción y no otra SQLException?

**Edit:** Si pongo `cpds.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(false)` la performance se me degrada mucho. No sé si es por la librería c3p0 o mi aplicación, pero me funciona mejor con `cpds.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(true)`.

Aún estoy por probar la solución de kdoomsday.

**Another Edit:**

Al probar la solución de kdoomsday hallé que `getErrorCode()` siempre retorna cero en este escenario. En realidad, hasta donde pude comprobar, no hay forma de saber si la conexión se restablece luego de haberse caído sin sacrificar la performance. Al final tuve que depender de un timer que chequeara la conexión cada pocos minutos y reiniciara el poll si la conexión se restablece luego de caerse.

Comment: No he trabajado antes con c3p0 pero el problema es simple: experimentas desconexión a la base de datos por pérdida de red y estás configurando para que c3p0 solo reintente 1 vez la reconexión a la base de datos, específicamente aquí: `cpds.setAcquireRetryAttempts(1)`. Es decir, si se pierde la conectividad 1 vez se reintentará conectar, y luego si se vuelve a perder ya no reintentará más veces, por ende tus conexiones están cerradas, tal como indica tu stacktrace: "com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.ResourcePoolException: Attempted to use a closed or broken resource pool".

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar la [documentación de c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) para comprender mejor sus parámetros de configuración y averiguar cómo resolver este problema.

Comment: Encontré esto, es muy probable que te sirva: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3511422/1065197

Answer (score 0):

La clase SQLException contiene un parámetro que corresponde al código de error. Puedes obtener este valor mediante la función `getErrorCode()` sobre la excepción. No puedo garantizar, pero si genera un código diferente que para otro tipo de excepciones, lo puedes utilizar. Si no, tendrás que hacer una comparación contra el mensaje de la causa.

Comment: Esto es un comentario más que una respuesta.